# Java XML Transformer repeating lines

Tags: java, xml, transform

I have a sporadic problem where a Java Transformer instance has duplicated lines at the end of the XML output.  Any ideas on why this is happening?  I'm unable to reproduce it reliably.  This is in a runnable jar where I write out a Document instance:

```
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(outPath));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Occasionally I end up with several lines from the end of the line being repeated. (note the extra data after the first closing `</Documents>` tag)  Is this an issue with the transform process or something with the way the file writer/result is set up?

```
....
    <RepositoryForm>
      <FormNumber>PP1301</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>12-99</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>PP1301_1299</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Coverage For Damage To Your Auto Exclusion Endorsement</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>8</FormPrintOrder>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <RepositoryForm>
      <FormNumber>GMIL4791</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>10-11</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>GMIL4791_1011</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Civil Union Endorsement</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>8</FormPrintOrder>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <GMIL931>
      <FormNumber>GMIL931PA</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>06-18</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>GMIL931PA_0618</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Pennsylvania Financial Responsibility Card</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>14</FormPrintOrder>
      <IDCards>
        <IDCard>
          <EffectiveDate>2051-01-05-06:00</EffectiveDate>
          <UnitInfo>
            <Unit>1</Unit>
            <Year>2017</Year>
            <Make>JAG</Make>
            <Model>F-PACE S AWD</Model>
            <VIN>removed</VIN>
          </UnitInfo>
        </IDCard>
      </IDCards>
    </GMIL931>
  </Document>
</Documents>der>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <RepositoryForm>
      <FormNumber>PP1301</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>12-99</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>PP1301_1299</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Coverage For Damage To Your Auto Exclusion Endorsement</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>8</FormPrintOrder>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <RepositoryForm>
      <FormNumber>GMIL4662</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>06-18</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>GMIL4662_0618</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Pennsylvania Notice</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>8</FormPrintOrder>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <RepositoryForm>
      <FormNumber>GMIL5519</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>06-18</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>GMIL5519_0618</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Notice To Policyholder - Paid In Full Discount</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>8</FormPrintOrder>
    </RepositoryForm>
    <GMIL931>
      <FormNumber>GMIL931PA</FormNumber>
      <FormEditionDate>06-18</FormEditionDate>
      <FormKey>GMIL931PA_0618</FormKey>
      <FormDesc>Pennsylvania Financial Responsibility Card</FormDesc>
      <FormPrintOrder>14</FormPrintOrder>
      <IDCards>
        <IDCard>
          <EffectiveDate>2051-01-06-06:00</EffectiveDate>
          <UnitInfo>
            <Unit>1</Unit>
            <Year>2017</Year>
            <Make>JAG</Make>
            <Model>F-PACE S AWD</Model>
            <VIN>removed</VIN>
          </UnitInfo>
        </IDCard>
      </IDCards>
    </GMIL931>
  </Document>
</Documents>
```

Comment: It sounds like your file is not truncated somehow. Maybe this is a bug with your JRE on your platform. Try truncate the file before writing, or just delete it if it sounds too tedious.

Comment: Are you using XSLT?

Comment: I'm not using XSLT.  The file should also be new as the filename is timestamped down to the seconds so I hadn't considered the truncation issue.  I did add a FileUtils.deleteIfExists(...) just in case to see if that helps.